# Using Feeds importer to import separate urls to same content-type

Tags: nodes, feeds

I'll try to parse out my problem laconicly:

I've two separate urls formatted as csv files that I want to import to the SAME content-type.

I'm using the same Feeds importer to accomplish this task, using the same unique identifier to import each url and update/overwrite all existing nodes.

Yet, for some reason I'm still getting new nodes when I should be getting updated nodes.

I have no clue where the process could be going wrong hence my post herein. Any help would be most emphatically appreciated.

David

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a direct solution to this issue, try set an unique field on the content type instead and use that instead of an UUID. Have a look at [Support unique targets in mappers](https://www.drupal.org/node/661606)